# RL Circuit Problem

Tags: inductor

[image]

Here is a problem related to the discharge of an RL circuit. Now, I am a bit skeptical about the answer. The answer to question 26(a) should be E/(R+r), right? The book shows a different answer. Please help.

Comment: Current through solenoid when switch is opened = E/r.... but not for long. Though you could also argue current will be zero "after" since it gives no time parameter for "after".

Comment: Switch S is the open key. You're correct - the books says the same thing. Can you tell me how you arrived at this conclusion?

Comment: basic rule of inductors.. **current can not change instantaneously**... whatever I was before you open the switch = I immediately after.

Comment: The point is, the parallel resistance R has no effect on the coil current *at the instant the switch is opened*. However, it does have an effect on how the current subsequently decays from there.

Comment: Hmmm. It does. In that case if I write E/(R+r), it'd be correct, I presume?

Comment: No. The value of the current during the decay varies with time, so whatever expression you write must be a function of time.

Comment: Nope... You know I is E/r so what is the voltage across the inductor immediately after the switch opens.

Comment: Something like \$i=\frac{E}{r}  e^{-t/\tau}\$?

Comment: You need to get E/(R+r) out of your head...

Comment: Trevor, I think yes, but doesn't R count?

Comment: The battery voltage is not relevant.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it

Comment: Yes, R does count, but in the time constant for the current decay only.

Comment: Aha, you mean, the steady state current that we are considering here is actually the current though the inductor at infinite time when it was charging?

Comment: Yup.. I'd assume that. Though the question does not implicitly state it, one has to assume S1 has been closed forever before T=0. That and the battery hasn't died... Typically sloppily written question though...

Comment: steady state load is R//r when closed and R+r when open but R>>r so we usually neglect R when close, leaving simply r when closed and R when opened.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ya that's the load on the battery though. Not the inductor current which the question is asking about.

Comment: **26b. is totally unanswerable.**

Comment: Trev, Heat = energy , Power= V²/r =Pd (Watts)  ...*t=E (Joules), temp, T depends on thermal R

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ya ya, but without stating a starting time, since t < 0 is already implied in the question, question does not compute. Though I guess you could write an equation to include that too, but me thinks that wont be the answer at the back...

Comment: 26 (b) is answerable. All they want you to find out is the amount of heat that the resistor will dissipate when the inductor's completely out of juice. That's equal to the amount of magnetic energy stored in the inductor at t=0

Comment: @Trevor: I think that perhaps the question was supposed to be what is the *power* dissipated in the coil (i.e., for t < 0), which would be \$E^2/r\$.

Comment: @user162228: It says heat generated *in the solenoid*.

Comment: @user162228 no some of the energy stored will be dissipated in resistor R.

Comment: @Trevor: Ha, this is my state now. I'm a 16 year old student preparing for JEE - the toughest exam of India - and I'm completely self taught. Guess the reason? The teachers around in my area aren't good enough. Now, I guess the books are like the teachers too.

Comment: Anyhoos... 26b could even be zero if you use 26a's poorly implied time period.. Personally I'd answer 26b (And a) as "Question closed due to "Unclear what you are asking!" LOL

Comment: @user162228 well good for you, keep it up. The good thing here is, when properly analyzed bad questions create analytical thought which is actually worth more than the answer in the back of the book.

Comment: @Trevor, the question is perfectly clear; it asks for the current after the switch is opened, and that is the exponential current. If you read 'steady state' or 'at the instant of opening the switch' then you're misreading the question.

Comment: @Chu, sorry mate, but that's your assumption. I agree there is nothing wrong with your assumption, but it's just that, an assumption. It's no more right or wrong than mine. Without qualification in the question we are both right. Schrodinger's cat would love this.

Comment: @Trevor It is a rational assumption. The last sentence begins 'at t=0, switch S is opened, calculate.... '. So clearly a and b , which are in the same sentence, refer to the condition where the switch is opened. Mate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, \$i(t) =\frac{E}{r} e^{-t/\tau}\$ is the correct form. \$i(0)=\frac{E}{r}\$ is the initial value of the current decay waveform.

The question then becomes, what is the correct value for the time constant \$\tau\$?

In this case, \$\tau = \frac{L}{R + r}\$

Comment: ... also, knowing the current, you can calculate the energy converted by r, hence heat energy resulting.

Comment: @Chu not without qualifying the time period you can't. Since 26a implies zero elapsed time, 26b leaves you hanging and making assumptions.

Comment: @Trevor, most of its converted after 5 time constants, or if you want to be pedantic, integrate to infinity.

Comment: @Chu not arguing that, but you are missing my point.. whatever.

Comment: @Chu: It might be academically interesting to analyze the incremental amount of energy dissipated by r after the switch opens, but it seems silly compared to the infinite amount of energy that it dissipated for t < 0. It will also be much less than the energy dissipated by R after the switch opens (i.e., most of the energy stored in the coil), given that R >> r (presumably).

Comment: The OP asks for the energy after the switch is opened. How else can the question be read.

Comment: @Chu: Actually, 26b doesn't mention the switch at all. That's another assumption you're making.

Comment: 26a and 26b are part of the same sentence, so they must relate to the preamble in that sentence. To me that says we're looking at t>0.